# What is the limit of Facebook friend requests you can receive?

Tags: facebook, facebook-friend-request

I'm asking this because I receive a lot of friend requests everyday, but I know that there's a moment in which if someone clicks on your "add as friend" a pop-up will appear saying something like "Sorry. This person has already a lot of pending requests".

So I want to know the limit of pending requests I can receive before the next person who adds me will see that "sorry" message.

Answer (score 2):

There's only the limit of having 5,000 friends and the unknown limit of friend requests you can **send**. The former is there because nobody can have so many active connections (if you're a public person wanting to be in touch with your fan base, you should use a Page not a profile). The latter is there to prevent spam and it's unknown for that reason.

Comment: I see, but there must be a limit anyway, since it happened to me twice; when I found on FB the Profile of a magazine, I sent them a friend request and the message appeared saying this person has reached a maximum quantity of pending friend requests.

Answer (score 0):

You can have approximately 1,000 friend requests before it says that.

I've reached that limit multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

5000 friends is maximum. Attend to those pending requests first.

Comment: Can you document this information?